# How to insert 'click here' link in ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, xml, adapter, expandablelistadapter, linkify

I am inserting a string from strings.xml in a ExpandableListView.Within ExpandableListView, I have a child TextView, in which I want to insert a link "click here" which redirect at www.google.com . When I am clicking whole row is clicked not "click here" text.Here is my code:

- strings.xml

  ```
   <string name="Help_seven_answer">Please <a href="https://accounts.google.com/"> click here</a> to Revoke access for closed.</string>
  ```
- Expendable.xml

> ```
>  <ExpandableListView
>                 android:id="@+id/lvExp"
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
> ```

within expendable.xml I am putting my textView as child.

```
  <TextView
              android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="17dip"
              android:paddingTop="5dp"
              android:paddingBottom="5dp"
              android:linksClickable="true"
              android:autoLink="web"
              android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
 />
```

In my fragment I am creating a Hash Map and accessing text as

> List seven = new ArrayList();
>           seven.add(context.getString(R.string.Help_seven_answer));

output I want : Please  [click here](https://accounts.google.com/) to Revoke access for closed.

Answer (score 0):

Pandit,

Try to duplicateparentstate=false to the textview that can solve your issue.

```
<TextView
          android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="17dip"
          android:clickable="true"
          android:duplicateParentState="false"
          android:paddingTop="5dp"
          android:paddingBottom="5dp"
          android:linksClickable="true"
          android:autoLink="web"
          android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
```

/>

Vinod